# Android: Change Screens

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My App starts and loads the first screen, then the users changes to the next screen by clicking a button with:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and then from there, the user changes to the next screen, again with:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

now there should be 3 screens on the stack and in this last screen, I want to go all the way back to the first screen, how do I do that with one click?
I want to send putExtra("") data from that last screen to the first screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

In NextActivity,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(NextActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  myIntent.putExtra("UserName",UserName);
   startActivity(myIntent);
```

In DashBoardActivity,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
UserName=intent.getStringExtra("UserName");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NextActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
// This will remove all activities which are on the top of DashboardActivity
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.putExtra("<Your data will be here>");
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 intent.putExtra("string",strValue);
 startActivity(intent);
```